# Check that an asynchronous event was only raised once

Tags: c#, events, nunit

When I write a unit test which needs to check that an *asynchronous* event is raised as it should, I usually do something like this:

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    var eventRaised = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    subject.SomeEvent += (s, e) => { eventRaised.Set(); };

    // Do something which should have triggered the event

    Assert.True(eventRaised.WaitOne(5000), "Event was not raised.");
}
```

However, in my current case the event is raised based on a a different event from an external system and I just discovered that I actually get duplicate events, which is not good. I can't change this other system so I need to filter out the duplicate events in my class. Luckily there is a simple way to check if it's duplicate, but now I'm wondering how I should change my unit test to make sure that my filtering is working correctly.

How would you write a unit test which checked that after a certain action was taken, a certain event is only raised once?

Comment: I'd probably do something in my code to prevent the dup, eg, keep a list of raised values, and accept that an event maybe raised with the same data, but, a given amount of time has to pass, I would probably keep a list of calls within that time period and if it exists fail silently, so the only test to confirm it only did once is to check for dups in a log etc

Comment: Use a counter in addition to your MRE.

Answer (score 2):

Add a counter to the Unit Test, and increment the counter any time the Event Handler is triggered.  Ensure that when the test is complete, the counter value is equal to 1.

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    int numEventsRaised = 0;
    subject.SomeEvent += (s, e) => { numEventsRaised++; };

    // Do something which should have triggered the event

    //As per the OP's example, we will wait 5 seconds to ensure
    //the async event has time to be raised.
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Assert.False((numEventsRaised == 0), "Event was not raised.");
    Assert.False((numEventsRaised > 1), "Event was raised more than once.");
}
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I'm thinking, but since the event is asynchronous this will fail unless something more is added. This *something more* is what I'm wondering what could look like and the reason for my question :)

Comment: You could just call Thread.Sleep(5000) if the object which raises the event is on another Thread.  That would essentially give you the same "padding" as eventRaised.WaitOne(5000), in your original example.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well. That unit test will take time since the delay have to expire (so that you are sure that an eventual second publish is caught).

Use a counter and try to decrease the timeout. 5 seconds seems a bit long (it depends on the external system)

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    var eventRaised = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    var counter = 0;
    subject.SomeEvent += (s, e) => { if (++counter) >= 2 eventRaised.Set(); };

    // Do something which should have triggered the event

    // you might want to decrease the timeout
    Assert.False(eventRaised.WaitOne(5000), "Event was not raised.");
    Assert.AreEqual(1, counter);
}
```

Comment: The above code will guarantee that the event is raised "At most once," but will not guarantee that the event is raised "at least once."  The OP wants to prove that his event is raised EXACTLY once; no more, no less.